# Retrieving and displaying a single record from database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two methods in my controller. The first is called `uploads` and it displays  all the records from a DB table, it looks like this :

```
 public function uploads()
    {
        //return Upload::all();
        $uploads = Upload::all();
        return view('uploads')->with('uploads',$uploads);
    }
```

This function is working and all the records are successfully retrieved in my view.

The issue is with the second method `upload` which aims to show a data for a single upload when its name is clicked from the list of uploads.

Currently, I have just this :

```
 public function upload($id)
{
    return Upload::find($id);
}
```

And I am not sure how to complete this functionality.

My view is looking like this :

```
 @extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <h1>Uploads</h1>
    @if(count($uploads)>0)
@foreach($uploads as $upload)
    <div class="well">
        <h3><a href="/uploads/{{$upload->id}}">{{$upload->name}}</a> </h3>
        <small>Written on {{$upload->created_at}}</small>
    </div>
        @endforeach
    @else
    <p>No uploads found</p>
    @endif

@endsection
```

I wasn't really sure what to put in `web.php`, so my routes look like this :

```
    Route::get('/uploads', function () {
    return view('uploads');
});

Auth::routes();
Route::get('/uploads','UploadController@uploads')->name('uploads');
```

Can someone help me make this work? I just want to see the associative array with the record from the database when I click on an upload's name. What do I need to add in routes and in my view?

Comment: So what's the target? Display only one on upload() method?

Comment: yes, display the one with the respective id

Comment: On the same filename upload.blade.php?

Comment: I have written it above : the  upload function aims to show a data for a single upload when its name is clicked from the list of uploads shown by the uploads function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Controller
public function uploads()
{
    $uploads = Upload::all();
    return view('uploads')->with('uploads', $uploads);
}
```

You can use Laravels IOC container here and let Laravel pass the correct Upload in your controller action.

```
public function showUploadDetail(Upload $upload)
{
    return view('uploadDetail')->with('upload', $upload);
}
```

Create a new blade file called `uploadDetail.blade.php` with the sample content:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
   <h1>Upload Detail</h1>
   <p>ID: {{ $upload->id }}</p>
@endsection
```

And as already mentioned by [fil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3721034/fil) adjust your route to:

```
Route::get('/upload/{id}', 'UploadController@upload')->name('upload');
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay try something like this

```
public function upload($id)
{ 
  $uploads = Upload::find($id);

  return view('uploads')
    ->with('uploads', $uploads);
}
```

and in your blade

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
   <h1>Uploads</h1>
   @if(is_array($uploads) and count($uploads) > 0)
      @foreach($uploads as $upload)
        <div class="well">
          <h3><a href="/upload/{{$upload->id}}">{{$upload->name}}</a> </h3>
          <small>Written on {{$upload->created_at}}</small>
        </div>
      @endforeach
   @else
     <div class="well">
       <h3><a href="/uploads/{{$uploads->id}}">{{$uploads->name}}</a> </h3>
       <small>Written on {{$uploads->created_at}}</small>
     </div>
   @endif

@endsection
```

In your route

```
Route::get('/upload/{id}', 'UploadController@upload')->name('upload');
```

Or you can create a separate blade, for single view, say the name of blade is upload.blade.php not uploads.blade.php for more clarity in term of the filename and purpose.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i tried it but it gives me this error : (2/2) ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\logoss\resources\views\uploads.blade.php)

Comment: you can use something like <div class="well">{{ dump($uploads) }} to see what actually is being passed

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the Routes to show the Single Record inside your web.php.

> Web.php

**so, Just add the Following Route to your web.php**

```
Route::get('/uploads/{upload_id}','UploadController@upload')->name('single.upload');
```

**Change your upload function with the Following Function inside your UploadController:**
This function retrieves the Upload Record and return that record to the View:

> Controller

```
public function upload($upload_id)
{
    $upload= Upload::find($upload_id);
    //var_dump($upload);   //Un-comment this line to show full Returned Data
    return view('view_upload',compact('upload'));
}
```

**And create the blade file with name view_upload.blade.php to show that single selected upload.**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
   <h1>Upload Detail</h1>
   <p>ID: {{ $upload->id }}</p>
   //Following Line Display all the Record.
   // var_dump($upload);
@endsection
```